# Google Search Console API error "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

Tags: python, google-search-console

I want to get result from search analytics query of Google Search Console API ([ref](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/searchanalytics/query)). Using API Explorer method on the right of the page, I get return 200 as a response, following with the json result. See the screenshot below. [image]

When this is created programmatically using python script, here is the credential method used (using google default credential)

```
credential, project = google.auth.default(
    scopes=[
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters'
    ],
    quota_project_id=project_id
)
service = build('searchconsole', 'v1', credentials=credential)
```

When test it in local, here is the error

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.somewebsite.com/searchAnalytics/query?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

Based on the error message, what scope is missing? Because the documentation only says to add the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters`

Foot note: Usage of oogle default credential is intentional, to avoid using service account key as authentication credential method.

Comment: I think should be used:
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly`

Would you try with it?

Comment: already try it, but the error still same, regarding insufficient authentication scopes.

Comment: Did you check the permission level? If not: Go to the Google Search Console website and sign in with the account that you are using to authenticate the API requests. Select the website that you are trying to access through the API. Click on the "Settings" icon in the navigation menu on the left-hand side. Click on "Users and permissions" in the drop-down menu. Look for the email address associated with the OAuth 2.0 client ID that you are using in your code. Check that the email address has the appropriate permission level (e.g., "Full" or "Read only") for the website's Search Console data.

Comment: Already login and open the Settings, but no section for "User and permissions". But I can see the the searchconsole performance of the url listed. Also I can get data from API test provided in https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/searchanalytics/query. But not yet found the way to collect the data with python lib

Comment: If you cannot find the "Users and permissions" section in the navigation menu, it is possible that you do not have sufficient permissions to access it. You may need to request access from the owner or administrator of the Google Search Console account.

Comment: hmm, it is that I can't get it via python, while I can get the data using API tester.